# Curious to know why over-watering leads to root-rot yet the same plant can be grown in water?

Tags: watering, plant-health, soil, plant-care, hydroponic

I bought a few pothos plants from home depot last summer, and from my investigation, it seemed they all died from root rot. I tried every thing I could to save them but they just would not stop. But at my work place, there is a pothos plant, set in a bottle of water, on the window pane in the kitchen that seems to be doing so well, even with no one really in charge of caring for it? There are a couple of those around the office and every now and then someone maybe changes the water and puts them back, and they don't die.How come?

Comment: I think part of the reason is that fungi (the real cause of root rot) tends to grow better in soil than water. Another reason is that pure water tends not to have a significant NPK value, and high nitrogen with low potassium and/or phosphorus, as might be found in some soils, can make a plant more susceptible to root issues. Did you give your plants high nitrogen fertilizer? Yet another reason is that roots in water are often exposed to more light than roots in soil, and fungi like it dark. It's not true that too much water always causes root rot. Roots may rot in water; pythium? probably not.